# Rainbow text on a surface in Asymptote

Tags: asymptote

I'm looking for a way to color a text rendered on the surface with a gradient. Below is an example showing the surface with the gradient and the text in black. How can the text color be changed?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{name=text}
import graph3;
import contour;
import palette;

size(8cm,IgnoreAspect);

currentprojection=orthographic(-10,-10,8);
limits((0,0,0),(5,10,12));

real f(pair z) {return (z.x+z.y)/(2+cos(z.x)*sin(z.y));}

surface s=surface(f,(0,0),(5,10),50,Spline);

draw(s,mean(palette(s.map(zpart),Rainbow())),black);

string text="lorum ipsum";
real uoffset=1; 
real voffset=1; 
real h=0.1;
draw(surface(xscale(0.9)*yscale(0.9)*text,s,uoffset,voffset,h));

\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post an MWE or at least indicate all the asymptote libraries you are loading for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, here you go then. I do not think that your choice of the surface is particularly nice, but this is just a matter of taste. The question is about drawing a text on a surface and giving it rainbow colors, which is actually not too difficult.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{name=text}
import graph3;
import contour;
import palette;

size(8cm,IgnoreAspect);

currentprojection=orthographic(-10,-10,8);
limits((0,0,0),(5,10,12));

real f(pair z) {return (z.x+z.y)/(2+cos(z.x)*sin(z.y));}

surface s=surface(f,(0,0),(5,10),50,Spline);

draw(s,red+opacity(0.4));//mean(palette(s.map(zpart),Rainbow())),black

string text="\textbf{lorum ipsum}";
real uoffset=1; 
real voffset=1; 
real h=0.1;
draw(surface(xscale(0.4)*yscale(0.4)*text,s,uoffset,voffset,h),mean(palette(s.map(zpart),Rainbow())),black);
//draw(surface(xscale(0.9)*yscale(0.9)*text,s,uoffset,voffset,h));

\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{name=text}
size(5cm);
pen[][] p={{white,grey,black},
           {red,green,blue},
           {cyan,magenta,yellow}};
latticeshade(texpath("text"),p);
\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm looking specifically for a way to render this command: `draw(surface(xscale(1)*yscale(1)*text,s,uoffset,voffset,h));` with a gradient ie. to have a text rendered both on the surface and in colour. Is there a way to use a pen inside the `draw` command?

Comment: @zbigniew Well, your question does not have an MWE. If you provide one, i.e. specify a suitable `f` and really bake an MWE, I may have a look at it.

Comment: Sorry for the vague original question. I just added an example. Would be grateful if you could take a look.

Comment: @zbigniew I added something, please have a look. It actually really only combines ingredients you were already using.

Comment: Just testing it further and the text doesn't render with gradient (like in your attached picture). Instead it is broken in segments and each is coloured with a random colour and the rainbow affect isn't really there. Is there a way to change it?

Comment: @zbigniew The output is really from the code above. Or am I misinterpreting your statement?